# Java cloudera impala connection unstable: with [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500151) Error setting/closing session: {0}

Tags: java, spring, cloudera, impala

I wrote a very simple Java app to query the Hadoop table (which is mange by someone else), but the connection is unstable. I tried to use [BasicDataSource](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.2.2/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html) to manage the connection, the same connection issue remains. Is this a Hadoop issue, or there is something I can do?

Here are my code:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class ImpalaConnection {


    private String impalaDriverName = "com.cloudera.impala.jdbc4.Driver";

    private BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();

    public ImpalaConnection() {
        //Set database driver name
        bds.setDriverClassName(impalaDriverName);
        //Set database url
        String serverName = ""; // my impala url
        String serverPort = "21050";
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:impala://" + serverName + ":" + serverPort +";SocketTimeout=0;" ;
        bds.setUrl(connectionUrl);
//        //Set database user
//        bds.setUsername(DB_USER);
//        //Set database password
//        bds.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
        //Set the connection pool size
//        bds.setInitialSize(1);
        bds.setMinIdle(5);
        bds.setMaxIdle(10);
        bds.setValidationQueryTimeout(100); // in second
        
    }

    private static class DataSourceHolder {
        private static final ImpalaConnection INSTANCE = new ImpalaConnection();
    }

    public static ImpalaConnection getInstance() {
        return DataSourceHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public BasicDataSource getBds() {
        return bds;
    }

    public void setBds(BasicDataSource bds) {
        this.bds = bds;
    }
    
}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.sql.*;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    ImpalaConnection im;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            runQuery(i);
        }

    }

    public static void runQuery(int k) {
        System.out.println(k);
        try {
            BasicDataSource bds = ImpalaConnection.getInstance().getBds();
            Connection con = bds.getConnection();
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT\n" +
                    "  msgs.messagepublishevent.convdetails.convid\n" +
                    "FROM \n" +
                    "dv_messagepublishevent_prq_local msgs,\n" +
                    "msgs.participants as participants\n" +
                    "WHERE msgs.year = 2020 \n" +
                    "LIMIT 10");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
            int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
                    if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
                    String columnValue = resultSet.getString(i);
                    System.out.print(columnValue + " " + rsmd.getColumnName(i));
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

While I was able to connect to Hadoop from time to time, sometimes it's Error stack is produced:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500151) Error setting/closing session: {0}.
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.openSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCCommonConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.impala.core.ImpalaJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1188)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.runQuery(DemoApplication.java:28)
Caused by: com.cloudera.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500151) Error setting/closing session: {0}.
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:159)
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2ClientWrapper.recv_OpenSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:146)
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2ClientWrapper.OpenSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.openSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCCommonConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.impala.core.ImpalaJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1188)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.runQuery(DemoApplication.java:28)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:19)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 23 more
```

Here is my dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudera.impala.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ImpalaJDBC4</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudera.impala.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>TCLIServiceClient</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: `String serverName = ""; // my impala url` -- do you connect to Impala thru load balancer, or to one of impalad's directly? If the former, LB might periodically be hitting an impalad which is unhealthy / down.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the impala jdbc client is unstable. Could you try upgrading the Impala JDBC driver from JDBC4 to JDBC41.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.cloudera.impala.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ImpalaJDBC41</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.4.1005</version>
</dependency>
```

Since you are using springboot you may also have to define the HSQL hibernate dialect for spring-boot, something as below:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

You can check more on details in [this blog](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2019/01/27/jdbc-connection-to-impala/).

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I have JDBC41, but I'll definitely check out HSQL dialect when I have a chance

Comment: Cloudera Impala jdbc driver package comes with all 3 version of jdbc. Jdbc4, Jdbc41 and Jdbc42. So i guess you too should have them. Jdbc4 is for the JRE version of 6 while Jdbc41 is for jre 7,8.